# Local User Profile Created on Server for Every ASP.NET Website User

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I have an asp.net (.net 3.5) website running on two Windows 2008 servers with IIS 7.  The web server contains the UI code, which calls the wcf web services on the app server.  These wcf services then make calls to an Oracle database.

My problem is that local user profiles are being created in C:\Users on the app server.  These local user profiles have the same name of user on the website.  I noticed that this happens when users change their password on the website.  Having a local user profile for every account on the website is now taking up a lot of space!

Does anybody have any idea why this might be happening and how I can stop it?  I have searched and searched and I could only find one person with the same problem as me on the windows forums.  Unfortunately, nobody answered his/her post.  Hopefully I have better luck here! :)

At first I thought it might work if I turned off the "load user profile" setting in IIS for all my app pools, but that didn't solve the problem.  **Edit:** I think this setting is responsible for created user profiles for the app pools and not the actual website users.

I'm considering changing the "Allow log on locally" setting in the Local Security Policy of the app server and removing "Users" because I think only "Administrators" need this right.  However, in my environment it is a bit of a pain to go through all the procedures to change settings like this and I'm not even sure if it will work, so I'm hoping to get some kind of response here before trying that.

**PrincipalContext/UserPrincipal**

I forgot to mention, I think I know the culprit code during which the profile is getting created.  Unfortunately, I don't have the ability to debug through this particular part of the code because it is in the web service so I can't tell you the exact line.  However, if I had to guess, I think the user profile is created during the following lines of code:

```
Dim pcDomain As New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, _strDomain, _strPath)
Dim upDomain As UserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pcDomain, strUserName)
upDomain.ChangePassword(strCurrentPassword, strNewPassword)
```

**Edit 2/19/2014**

I'd also like to add, the users for the website are authenticated with active directory.

Comment: Where are you storing user's profile?

Comment: The user profiles are being created in C:\Users along with the user profiles of people who actually rdp into the server

Comment: All that belongs to the DDBB..

Comment: What is DDBB?  Could you expand it so I have an better time searching about it?  I assume you don't mean The Dirty Dozen Brass Band...or maybe you do.....haha

Comment: DDBB = Database. Sorry for the acronym. See: 
http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84376/inside-the-aspnet-user-profile-mechanism/
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.profile.sqlprofileprovider.aspx

Comment: Thank you for clarifying and for the links! However, our code does not use that sqlprofileprovider.  Your links did remind of some additional information I should have included.  I'm adding information about UserPrincipal in my original post.

Comment: Can you check the setting of `<identity impersonate` in `web.config` and post?

Comment: Hi, there is no "impersonate" set in my web.config.  Thanks!

Comment: I have the same behavior in an application and I can tell that the ChangePassword is the culprit, but I could not figure out why.

Comment: Here is a Workaround, which does not use ADSI and cirmcumvents the Profile createion: http://blogs.technet.com/b/fieldcoding/archive/2013/01/09/resetting-passwords-honoring-password-history-or-what-s-happening-under-the-hood-when-changing-resetting-passwords.aspx

Comment: I know this is years old, but did you ever solve this? I seem to be having the same problem, and I don't know what to do.